# Getting all possible combinations of nested dictionary

Tags: python

I'm trying to get every possible combination of a form with multi choice answers

I have this dict:

```
{
"question": "Gender?",
"choices": ["Male", "Female", "Non Bynary", "Other"],
"child":{
  "question": "Country?",
  "choices": ["USA", "Canada", "France", "Other"],
  "children":{
    "question": "Age?",
    "choices": ["<20", "20-30", "30-40", "40+"],
  }
 }
}
```

What I want to obtain is:

```
[
 {
  "choice": "Male",
  "child":{
   "choice": "USA",
   "child":{
    "choice": "<20"
   }
  }
 },
 {
  "choice": "Male",
  "child":{
   "choice": "USA",
   "child":{
    "choice": "20-30"
   }
  }
 },
 {
  "choice": "Male",
  "child":{
   "choice": "USA",
   "child":{
    "choice": "30-40"
   }
  }
 },
]
```

and so on, I tried itertools and a simple recursive for but nothing seems to work, can you help me?

i tried doing this

```
list_children = {key + str(j): dict(zip(val.keys(), k))
                     for key, val in hierarchical_questions.items()
                     for j, k in enumerate(product(*val.values()))}
```

but it returns to me

```
'str' object has no attribute 'values'
```

i tried this but got stuck on recursive statement

```
def test_list_choices(hierarchical_questions, parent_choice=None):
    if parent_choice is None:
        parent_choice = {}
    list_children = []
    for choice in hierarchical_questions['choices']:
        if parent_choice is None:
            parent_choice = choice
            list_children.append({
                "choice": choice.choice,
            })
        elif parent_choice == choice:
            for child in hierarchical_questions['child']:
                for child_choise in child["child"]:
                    #list_children.append()
                    print(child_choise)
    return list_children
```

And many other recursive functions which however cycle infinitely.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If efficency is not what you're looking for, you can do it with a simple recursive function:

```
def generate_combinations(question_dict, combination=None):
    if combination is None:
        combination = []

    if "choices" not in question_dict:
        return [combination]

    combinations = []
    for choice in question_dict["choices"]:
        current_combination = combination + [{"choice": choice}]
        if "child" in question_dict:
            child_combinations = generate_combinations(question_dict["child"], current_combination)
            combinations.extend(child_combinations)
        elif "children" in question_dict:  # Added for children key
            child_combinations = generate_combinations(question_dict["children"], current_combination)
            combinations.extend(child_combinations)
        else:
            combinations.append(current_combination)

    return combinations
```

Comment: I tried but it returns me KeyError: 'choices', if i add a control if "choices" in question_dict instead it cycles infinitely

Comment: Ok but that means that you're using an input that is not what you've posted in the question, since I can see 'choices' among the keys of your input. Anyway, I've added the choices control, and with the input you've provided it runs just fine

Comment: I'll rephrase: the function cycles for a while but at a certain point it gives me KeyError:'choices', i already checked all the input

Comment: Then I'd suggest to print the input in order to check where it stops working and post it here, since with the data provided I'm not able to replicate the issue

Comment: I solved the key problem by adding a check on the last one in the list but now it cycles infinitely, it has been running for at least 10 minutes

Comment: Again, with the input you provided in the question the code is working fine, so until you provide the input that causes problems, there isn't much we can do

Comment: I think the problem lies in the fact that with at least 12 questions with at least 4 possible answers each there are at least 4^12 combinations